# Xamarin.Forms (IOS): Best practice to process some data before app is closed

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Let's assume I have the situation when I should send some data to a server before app is closed (for example by app manager, just unloading the application from the memory using the Application Manager)

I could override `OnSleep` method (what I do now):

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    CommonModel dataList = GetCommonModel();

    foreach(var data in dataList)
    {
        if (await ProcessDataAsync(data))
        {
            UpdateDataModel(data); 
            // I need to know that sent data was updated on server successfully. 
            // In this case ProcessDataAsync returns true
        }
    }
}
```

but problem is I have to wait some response from server to save current state of object (otherwise I will send similar data to server while app is open)

For now debugger waits for response even when app is unloaded and all works fine but I can't check this case on real device for now and really don't sure it's a best practice to resolve this situation.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: you can use Task.Deplay(...) to wait on same method

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a [background service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#background-transfers)